# Check if split token came from left or right

Tags: java

I need to set the variables `termLast / termFirst` on a string of the form `LastName,FirstName` where either part can be omitted.

The following are valid and should be set accordingly,

```
,John
Smith,
Smith,John
```

At least one token will always be present. If I do

```
String termWhole = null, termLast = null, termFirst = null;
String[] tokens = str.split(",");
termLast = tokens[0];
termFirst = (tokens.length > 1 ? tokens[1] : null);
```

that assumes the rightward direction. Any suggestions on bidirectional parsing? The goal is to have the variables set correctly.

Comment: By "bidirectional parsing", do you mean accepting inputs in the form `FirstName,LastName`? Or something else?

Comment: The inputs specified should go into their respective variables. If FirstName only was specified as `,John` then the firstName var should be set, lastName var = null, and vice-versa. Whether something is first/last is denoted by the position before/after the comma.

Comment: @geneb. That's not what is commonly understood by "bidirectional parsing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split with a negative second parameter:

```
String[] tokens = str.split(",", -1);
```

so as to keep empty tokens on the end of the string. Then:

```
termLast = tokens[0].isEmpty() ? null : tokens[0];
termFirst = tokens[1].isEmpty() ? null : tokens[1];
```